# my 2 total r mixed with each other how can i separate them?

Tags: php

i am going to create a online card exchange store where they can buy and sell their card so i made 2 cart system. 1 for incoming card and 1 for outgoing card. all is going well accept the total. here is my code please help me.

```
<?php
// cart function for card in 
function cardin () {
foreach($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
        if ($value >0) {
            if (substr($name, 0, 5)=='cain_') {
                $id = substr($name, 5, (strlen($name)-5));
                $get = mysql_query('SELECT id, name, inprice FROM cards WHERE id='.mysql_real_escape_string((int)$id));
                while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)){
                    $sub = $get_row['inprice']*$value;
                echo '<table align="center" width="900" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td width="382" align="center">'.$get_row['name'].'</td>
    <td width="89" align="center">'.$value.'</td>
    <td width="121" align="center">' .$get_row['inprice'].'</td>
    <td width="124" align="center">'.$sub.'</td>
    <td width="79" align="center"><a href="cart.php?removein='.$id.'">[-]</a></td>
    <td width="79" align="center"><a href="cart.php?addin='.$id.'">[+]</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
// cart funciotn for out
function cardout () {
foreach($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
        if ($value >0) {
            if (substr($name, 0, 5)=='caou_') {
                $id = substr($name, 5, (strlen($name)-5));
                $get = mysql_query('SELECT id, name, outprice FROM cards WHERE id='.mysql_real_escape_string((int)$id));
                while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)){
                    $sub = $get_row['outnprice']*$value;
                echo '<table align="center" width="900" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td width="382" align="center">'.$get_row['name'].'</td>
    <td width="89" align="center">'.$value.'</td>
    <td width="121" align="center">' .$get_row['outprice'].'</td>
    <td width="124" align="center">'.$sub.'</td>
    <td width="79" align="center"><a href="cart.php?removeout='.$id.'">[-]</a></td>
    <td width="79" align="center"><a href="cart.php?addout='.$id.'">[+]</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
/////total function///////
///////////////////////// this is my problem ////////////////
// totalin funciotn similar to cart funciont only doing for return the total //////////////
function totalin () {
    foreach($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
        if ($value >0) {
            if (substr($name, 0, 5)=='cain_') {
                $id = substr($name, 5, (strlen($name)-5));
                $get = mysql_query('SELECT id, inprice FROM cards WHERE id='.mysql_real_escape_string((int)$id));
                while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)){
                    $sub = $get_row['inprice']*$value;
                }
            }
            $total += $sub;
        }
    }
    return $total;
}
//////total out function
function totalout () {
    foreach($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
        if ($value >0) {
            if (substr($name, 0, 5)=='caou_') {
                $id = substr($name, 5, (strlen($name)-5));
                $get = mysql_query('SELECT id, outprice FROM cards WHERE id='.mysql_real_escape_string((int)$id));
                while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)){
                    $sub = $get_row['outprice']*$value;
                }
            }
            $total += $sub;
        }
    }
    return $total;
}

$balance = totalin () - totalout ();
echo $balance;
```

how can i fix my problem? this is my first website so i dont know much more about so please help me guys. please answer with code// please// please//please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where you are declaring `$total`, so perhaps you're using a global for this?  Just make these locals inside of your total functions.

And if you're not using a global, and just declaring `$total` in its first assignment, you're probably getting an "Undefined variable" warning.

---

**EDIT**:  here's how I would modify your existing total functions:

```
function totalin () {
    $tin=0;
    foreach($_SESSION as $name => $value){
        if($value >0 && substr($name, 0, 5) == 'cain_') {
            $id = substr($name, 5, (strlen($name)-5));
            $get = mysql_query('SELECT id, inprice FROM cards WHERE id='.mysql_real_escape_string((int)$id));
            while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)){
                $sub = $get_row['inprice']*$value;
                $tin += $sub;
            }
        }
    }
    return $tin;
}

function totalout () {
    $tout=0;
    foreach($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
        if ($value >0 && substr($name, 0, 5)=='caou_'){
            $id = substr($name, 5, (strlen($name)-5));
            $get = mysql_query('SELECT id, outprice FROM cards WHERE id='.mysql_real_escape_string((int)$id));
            while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)){
                $sub = $get_row['outprice']*$value;
                $tout += $sub;
            }
        }
    }
    return $tout;
}
```

Comment: please look my last 2 function they r only for total

Comment: Yes I see them...in both of them, the first time you mention $total variable is in assignment statement.

Comment: $total is amount of $subs i mean $total = $sub+$sub+$sub and so ok tell me the way how can i get my 2 totals from thoes functions